Optimization problem for inverse problem on Maxwell-equations
i've been working on a project of mine, which involves the Maxwell-equations. For some context, the problem that i want to solve, is that given some boundary measurements of the potential $\Phi_{measured}$ on $\Gamma$, i want to calculate the conductivity for the whole $\Omega$ domain. This is done by first solving the forward problem to obtain the potentials along the whole domain, then comes the inverse problem, which calculates the conductivities of the domain. The important part is that i know that the conductivity changes periodically in time, so i assume, that the conductivity can be written as $\sigma(\vec{r},t) = \sigma_0 + \delta\sigma(\vec{r},t)$ and this implies, that the potential can be found in the same form as $\phi(\vec{r},t) = \phi_0 + \delta\phi(\vec{r},t)$.
So if i use the given Maxwell-equations for stationary flow:
$$\nabla(J) = 0 $$ given that $$J = \sigma E$$ and $$E = -\nabla \phi$$ we can arrive at the fact, that $$\nabla \cdot (\sigma (-\nabla\phi)) = 0$$ Substituting $\sigma$ and $\phi$ into this equation gives: $$\nabla \cdot((\sigma_0 + \delta\sigma)(\nabla\phi_0 + \nabla\delta\phi)) = 0$$ This can be written as:
$$ \nabla \cdot ((\sigma_0 + \delta \sigma )(\nabla \phi_0 + \nabla \delta \phi)) = \nabla \cdot (\sigma_0 \nabla \phi_0 + \sigma_0 \nabla \delta\phi + \delta \sigma \nabla \phi_0 + \delta\sigma \nabla\delta\phi) = 0$$
We assume, that the second order term can be neglected $\delta\sigma\nabla\delta\phi \approx 0$ and also that $\nabla \cdot (\sigma_0 \nabla\phi_0)=0$ so the equation reduces to:
$$ \nabla \cdot (\sigma_0 \nabla\delta\phi) + \nabla \cdot (\delta \sigma \nabla \phi_0) = 0$$
Now using the fact, that both conductivity and potiential changes periodically in time, we can write them in the form of a Fourier series:
$$ \delta\sigma = \sum_n \Sigma_n e^{i\omega_n t}$$
$$ \delta\phi = \sum_n \Phi_ne^{i\omega_n t}$$
By substituting this into the equation above, we get:
$$ \sigma_0\nabla\cdot(\nabla\sum_n \Phi_n e^{j\omega_n t}) + \sum_n \nabla\cdot(\Sigma_ne^{j\omega_n t}\nabla\phi_0) = 0$$
$$ \sigma_0\nabla\cdot(\nabla\sum_n \Phi_n e^{j\omega_n t}) + \sum_n (\Sigma_n e^{j \omega_n t} \nabla \cdot\nabla\phi_0 + e^{j \omega_n t} \nabla\Sigma_n \cdot \nabla\phi_0) = 0$$
$$\sum_n \left[e^{i \omega_n t}(\sigma_0\Delta\Phi_n + \Sigma_n\Delta\phi_0 + \nabla\Sigma_n \cdot \nabla \phi_0) \right] = 0$$
Since all $e^{i \omega_n t}$ are independent of each other, the equation should hold true, for each component. So this means that for frequency $\omega_m$ the following should be true:
$$ \sigma_0\Delta\Phi_m + \Sigma_m\Delta\phi_0 + \nabla\Sigma_m\cdot\nabla\phi_0 = 0$$
And assuming that $\Delta\phi_0 = 0$ we get the following:
$$\sigma_0\Delta\Phi_m + \nabla \Sigma_m \cdot \nabla \phi_0 = 0$$
The equation which describe the optimization problem can be written as:
$$J(\sigma) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M(\Phi_{measured}^{(k)} - \Phi_{calculated}^{(k)}(\sigma))^2 + \alpha R(\sigma)$$
And basically what im trying to do is, minimize this error, by an iterative method, which changes $\sigma$ the way $J(\sigma)$ is minimized.
I've done some research on the topic, and found, that one could try the so called $\textit{adjoint state method}$ to solve this problem where we construct a Lagrangian $L$:
$$L(\Sigma_m, \Phi_m, \lambda) = J(\Sigma_m) + \int_\Omega \lambda (\sigma_0\Delta\Phi_m + \nabla \Sigma_m \cdot \nabla\phi_0)d\vec{r}$$
And find the stationary points based on the Euler-Lagrange equations:
$$ \frac{\delta L}{\delta \Phi_m}=0, \frac{\delta L}{\delta \lambda}=0, \frac{\delta L}{\delta \Sigma_m}=0$$
So basically i want to minimize $J(\Sigma_m)=  \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^M(\Phi_{measured}^{(k)} - \Phi_{calculated}^{(k)}(\Sigma_m))^2 + \alpha R(\Sigma_m)$ with the differential equation $\sigma_0\Delta\Phi_M + \nabla\Sigma_m\cdot\nabla\phi_0=0$ as it’s constraint.
My question, is this approach right, or are there other methods, that are more suited for my problem? If not, since i'm pretty new to functional/variatonal analisys, how one should solve the Euler-Lagrange equations, and how could they be used for my optimization problem?
